# Stopping TFS 2010 controller from using an agent based on tags

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

I am using TFS 2010 and have a build machine that contains a single build controller running 2 agents.

I have worked out that I can assign a tag of "Nightly" to my 2nd agent and then edit the Build Definition for my Nightly Builds in TFS to only use an agent that has the tag of "Nightly".

Easy enough.

However, the issue here is that if a normal build (Such as dev/CI) came along, it could - in theory- use my nightly agent, which I don't want to happen.

I could go around all our development builds (20+) and add in a `tags=normal` and tag my primary build agent with `normal`, but this then relies on people remembering to tag up new builds in the future.

Is there a way to set up my build agent in TFS's Server Admin, so that it will ONLY run items with specific tags? Or is my "go around the houses" approach the only logical way?

**Edit**

I got around this in the end by making all my builds look for "matchExactly" on empty tags, which means my "nightly" tagged agent will never be used for CI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the default for build definitions says MatchExactly and has an empty Tags Filter field.  This means that by default build definitions will only run on Build Agents that have ZERO tags.  So the behavior you desire should be the default, when you tag your build agent with the Nightly tag, no builds will run on that agent unless somebody explicitly goes in and changes the default Agent settings for that build def.

Answer (score 0):

I expect that this agent is already running on it's own server, otherwise there'd be no reason to single it out.

You could give this specific build agent it's own build controller, that way chances of a build associated to the "CI" build controller are zero. unless people chose the incorrect Build Controller for their build definition.

This way you also won't have to go about changing the current build definitions.